# How do I make Roslyn aka MSBuildWorkspace behave the same way Visual Studio/MSBuild do? (aka "ResolveComReferences problem")

Tags: .net, msbuild, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to make Roslyn/MSBuildWorkspace work on some older .NET Framework projects. Those occasionally have COM references, some of them incorrect.
Compiling in Visual Studio works with warnings:

```
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ResolveComReference, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2977,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "ffffffff-0000-0000-0000-0000000fffff" version 3.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2977,5): warning MSB3305: Processing COM reference "VAccessLib" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Actian\Zen\bin\ACBtr732.ocx". Type library importer has encountered an interface not derived from IUnknown: 'ISWData'.
2>  ResolveComReference -> C:\ResolveComReference\bin\Debug\ResolveComReference.dll
```

Calling `MSBuild.exe` (without any parameters) compiles the project with warnings as well, they are shown in the `ResolveComReferences` section of verbose output.

But doing it from my code fails (the code is the usual: `workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(); var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);`).

```
Msbuild failed when processing the file 'C:\ResolveComReference\ResolveComReference.csproj' with message: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets: (2977, 5): The "ResolveComReference" task could not be instantiated from "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Msbuild failed when processing the file 'C:\ResolveComReference\ResolveComReference.csproj' with message: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets: (2977, 5): The "ResolveComReference" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.
```

and then additionally because of a project reference

```
Found project reference without a matching metadata reference: C:\TestProjects\_EmptyProject48\code.csproj
```

All this happens using code from the project template "Standalone Code Analysis Tool". Updating the referenced nuget packages doesn't help.

How do I make it work?

I *think* I could work around this by using `AdhocWorkspace` everywhere instead and manually parsing the sln and csproj files (see [LegacyWorkspaceLoader](https://github.com/RendleLabs/LegacyWorkspaceLoader)), but I really rather not, especially because I **see** `MSBuild.exe` working as expected on the same solution.

Example COMReference item:

```xml
    <COMReference Include="some_unexisting_library">
      <Guid>{FFFFFFFF-0000-0000-0000-0000000FFFFF}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>3</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>aximp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
    </COMReference>
```

Comment: This has little to do with COMReference, it can't find Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll.  File-not-found, the most basic mishap.  Be sure to add the Nuget package for it.

Comment: I can see in the Modules window when I set a breakpoint that the `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll` is loaded from the VS folder

Comment: That makes little sense for a "standalone tool", nor does the exception message complain about finding the wrong version.  Use the Nuget package.

Comment: Yes, both the name and the exception are confusing and neither one was my choice :)

Comment: If by the "nuget package" you mean the "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core", adding it only changes where the dll is loaded from (now it's the app folder instead of VS), errors remain the same.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually slightly different: "Msbuild failed when processing the file ... Cannot get the file path for type library "ffffffff-0000-0000-0000-0000000fffff" version 3.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))". So I get to see why it fails, still don't get it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody running into issues like this, try upgrading to the 4.9.0-2.final versions of the Roslyn packages; MSBuildWorkspace has been significantly changed in that version and should avoid issues like this now.